# How can I use Redis as a session store for JBoss 7 EAP?

Tags: session, jboss, jboss7.x

I've got two applications running in JBoss 7 EAP in which I want to store session information in Redis.  Additionally, I want to be able to use a user-defined key to load/store the session in Redis.

In essence, I want to use a JWT token to encrypt/secure the JSESSIONID, and extract the sessionId from the token and load the corresponding session from Redis.

Is this feasible?  The only documentation I found is something about using Infinispan as a session store, but I don't want to use Infinispan.  Is there anyway to swap that out for Redis and control the store/lookup key mechanism?

From what I can tell, I can create a custom implementation for `io.undertow.server.session.SessionManager` and `io.undertow.server.session.SessionConfig`, but I am not sure I understand how to register them, nor even all the components I need to accomplish this.

Is there any documentation or examples that can help?

Comment: See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-1898?focusedCommentId=12798083&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-12798083 and http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.2.0/index.html#servlet-extensions

Comment: @federicosierra thanks for link.  I've been reading that for the last while and I think I understand vaguely how to create my own SessionManager, but can't find any docs referring to providing my own SessionConfig implementation.  Where/how is that controlled or configured?

Comment: I think you can do it installing the `SessionAttachmentHandler` (Eg: `SessionAttachmentHandler sessattach = new SessionAttachmentHandler(SessionManager, SessionConfig);`) in handler chain.

Comment: @FedericoSierra Thanks - I've been trying to read up about the SessionAttachmentHandler, but having difficulty finding how/where it is configured.  Additionally, the javadocs seem to indicate that there is a different mechanism that must be used for Servlets.  I have a small concern that there would be two different areas which would have to configure something so critical/universal in SessionManagement.  Finally, the SessionConfig object is also passed into the handler as well, so I'm wondering if there isn't somewhere higher up in the chain to configure which implementation(s) to use.

Comment: Seeing the wildfly code, I think you can use a `SessionConfigWrapper` to achieve your goal. For example I implemented a simple project to change the `SessionManager` and wrap the `SessionConfig` https://github.com/fedesierr/custom-session-manager-example/blob/master/src/main/java/io/undertow/example/session/CustomSessionManagerExtension.java#L25

Comment: @federicosierra Thanks for the awesome example. I think that may be part of three missing link. My question though is if the DeploymentInfo object provides ability to use a wrapper to wrap the SessionConfig object, it implies that it still expects the original SessioNInfo object to continue to live. So I'm wondering if there isn't anther way to replace it with my own implementation. Additionally, I see a setServletSessionConfig - you you think that implies a  different object/mechanism for servlets as well?

Comment: Eric, I have based my example in how Wildfly wrap the session config when the web application is distributable https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/undertow/src/main/java/org/wildfly/extension/undertow/deployment/UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java#L554. Of my point of view you can keep the original session config (given that you don't know what is the context of your application, cluster, replication etc).

Comment: Also undertow wrap your session with ServletContextSessionConfig https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/servlet/src/main/java/io/undertow/servlet/spec/ServletContextImpl.java#L166 in a servlet context.